# Making a text field uneditable and not just readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i click on a `textfield`, i get a dropdown so the user could select a value from the list.

After the user selects the date from the dropdown, he/she could edit the date by even adding characters to it. So i want to find a way to prevent this. I thought of making the field un-editable. So i used `readonly` but, this prevents the user from clicking and displaying the list. So can someone tell me how can i make the field uneditable.

```
<input id="datePiccc" type="text" class="dates" />
```

Comment: Make the textbox readonly, then bind onto the `click` event to show your dropdown

Comment: @Johan wouldn't `disabled=""` parameter disables the text field from being insert? (_if he's inserting the values_)

Comment: @yaqoob Corrent. I missread the question

Comment: @Johan disabled="true" is just like readonly, i am unable to click.

Comment: Is it the jQUery ui datepicker?

Comment: `readonly` fields can still receive click events, and the user can even select text and copy it to the clipboard - they just can't edit the value, because "readonly" and "uneditable" mean the same thing. Please show the code that does the drop-down and maybe we can help you with that.

Comment: @nnnnnn I am using http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/ .  am following the first example code. and i want the field to be non editable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the below code. This will make the text input field clickable but when the user types in anything, nothing would happen.

```
document.getElementById('datePiccc').onkeydown = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/cNJfs/)

---

As pointed out by nnnnnn, `onkeydown` is a better option than `onkeypress` as it would stop the delete and backspace key functions.

You could add the below also to your code to nullify Cut and Paste events<sup>1</sup>. (**Note**: Not doing anything for Copy as that operation isn't going to change the value of the text field).

```
document.getElementById('datePiccc').oncut = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
document.getElementById('datePiccc').onpaste = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

<sup>1</sup> I think these should work in all browsers. Currently tested in Chrome 31, Opera 15, IE10 and FireFox 24. (Note: In IE10, there is an `x` mark which appears on the right side of the input field which when clicked clears the entire field value. Could not find a way around this.)

Comment: Your code (and fiddle) don't stop the user from changing the value in the field. Even ignoring copy/cut/paste operations done via mouse-click or the Edit menu your code doesn't stop the delete or backspace keys from working. You could use `onkeydown` instead of `onkeypress`, that should stop delete/backspace, but then there are still those pesky mouse and/or edit menu based changes...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes, `onkeydown` would have been better. Agreed on that. For the others give me a few minutes, I am trying to take in the entire thing.

Comment: I get this error `4
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'oncut' of null `

Comment: @sharonHwk: Are you putting this code in the `<head><script>...</script></head>` tag? This error normally happens when the JS code is executed before the element is available. Try moving the script to jus before the `</body>` tag (or) enclose it within a `window.onload`.

Comment: @sharonHwk: Can you upload your source file to some location (say jsFiddle) so that I can have a look at it?

Comment: @sharonHwk: That fiddle is working fine. I don't see any errors in the console. Can I move this to chat?

Comment: Yes, it works in the fiddle. I don't have a clue why. Anyway, the textfield is still editable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38180/discussion-between-harry-and-sharon-hwk)

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the text field is being set in javascript. If so, you can use the following line to `disable` the field:

`document.getElementById('datePiccc').disabled=true;`

The input will remain as it is and the value from the selection field can also be set.

Answer (score 4):

Disable the input in JQuery as

```
$("#datePiccc").attr("disabled", true);
```

And in pure JS

```
document.getElementById('datePiccc').disabled = true;
```

May be this can help!